# Check if one number is a multiple of another in php

Tags: php, math, multiplication

I am trying to build a function that checks one number is a multiple of another. I tried the below solution, it works for integer values but not for double or float values. When I tried double value it gives me an error like this

**Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero**

```
My Solution which I tried
function checkIfMult($input,$toBeChecked){
    return $toBeChecked % $input === 0; 
}
checkIfMult(0.3,168.3);
```

Comment: Use `fmod` rather than `%`. But beware: floating point arithmetic is approximate, it might not be exactly `0`.

Comment: <?php
function checkIfMult($toBeChecked, $input)
{
 $tempMod = (float) ($toBeChecked / $input);
 $tempMod = ( $tempMod - (int) $tempMod ) * $input;
 return $tempMod === 0;
}
echo checkIfMult(168.3, 0.3);
?>